# How to map a list of items into another list of buckets, given a key for each item?

Tags: java, hash, bucket

I have a list of items, say `List<Item> listOfItems` and each item has a key, say `String cluster_key`. I want to cluster all items with the same `cluster_key` into a bucket, giving me the result `List<Bucket> listOfBuckets`. The list of buckets starts off empty.

Any suggests on how to do this elegantly Java? Perhaps with hashing?

I can think of 2 implementations that are less than elegant:

- brute force, where we traverse the `listOfItems`, and for each item, traverse the list of buckets until we find a match. If we find a match, add the item to the bucket. Else,

.

```
for item in listOfItems {
    for bucket in listOfBuckets {
        if item.getKey() equals bucket.getKey()
            add item to bucket
        else
            create new bucket
            add item to bucket
            add bucket to listOfBuckets
    }
}
```

- sorting, then cluster:

.

```
sort listOfItems by their cluster_key;
get first item from listOfItems;
create a bucket, currentBucket, with key: firstItem.getKey()
add first item to bucket
for item in listOfItems, starting at the second item {
    if item.getKey() equals currentBucket.getKey()
        add item to currentBucket
    else
        create new bucket
        add item to new bucket
        add new bucket to listOfBuckets
        set new bucket to currentBucket
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to group items by the same key is to iterate through your list and add each item to the correct bucket (creating buckets when needed) as you go, which is similar to your first example.

But if you use a HashMap for your bucketList, you can add items to your bucket in constant time, which will give you an algorithm with O(n) instead of O(n^2) complexity .

Not tested but you get the idea

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Item>> bucketList = new HashMap();

for (Item i : listOfItems) {
    if(!bucketList.containsKey(i.getKey()) {
        bucketList.put(i.getKey(),new ArrayList());
    }

    buckList.get(i.getKey()).add(item);
}
```